# Modifying swift [CChar] arrays in C functions without returning value

Tags: c, swift

I started learning C and wanted to try some of the Swift-C interoperability.

I have a small C function which reads me a file and concatenates some useful letters into a char* variable. After some testing, I cannot find a way to pass my obtained char* data back to swift. I have written a small dummy code to illustrate what I am trying to achieve.

```
var letters: [CChar] = []

functionWithArray(&letters)

print("Back in swift: \(letters)")
```

And the C function is:

```
void functionWithArray(char* letters) {
    
    int arrayLenght = 5;
    int testLenght = 10; // Expand array to this value (testing)
    int currentArrayPosition = 0; //Keep track of the assigned values
    
    letters = malloc(sizeof(char)*arrayLenght);
    
    while (currentArrayPosition < testLenght) {
        
        if (currentArrayPosition == arrayLenght) {
            arrayLenght++;
            letters = realloc(letters, sizeof(char)*arrayLenght);
        }
        
        letters[currentArrayPosition] = *"A";
        ++currentArrayPosition;
    }
    
    printf("End of C function: %s\n", letters);
}
```

I get this as an output:

> End of C function: AAAAAAAAAA
>
> Back in swift: []
>
> Program ended with exit code: 0

As you can see, inside the C function I've got the desired result, but back in swift I could not find a way to obtain the modified array. I do not return *letters* directly with the function because I need to return more values from that function. I'm new to C so please be kind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two main issues with your approach here — one in C and one in Swift:

1. In C, function parameters are passed *by value*, and are effectively mutable local variables. That means that when `functionWithArray` receives `char *letters`, `letters` is a local variable containing a pointer value to the buffer of `letters` in memory. Importantly, that means that `letters` is assignable, but not in the way that you think:

   ```
   letters = malloc(sizeof(char)*arrayLenght);
   ```

   allocates an entirely new buffer through `malloc`, and assigns the newly-created pointer value to your *local `letters` variable*. Before the assignment, `letters` is a pointer to the buffer you were getting from Swift; after, to an unrelated buffer in memory. These two buffers are completely unrelated to one another, and because `letters` is just a local variable, this assignment is not propagaged in any way outside of the function.

   Note that this is just a rule of C: as you learn more C, you'll likely discover that in order to assign a variable from inside of a function to outside of a function, you need to wrap the variable in *another* layer of pointers and write through *that* pointer (e.g., you would need to receive `char **letters` and assign `*letters = malloc(...)` to have any effect on a variable being passed in — *and* the variable couldn't be passed in directly, but rather, its *address* would need to be passed in).

   However, you can't generally make use of this fact because,
2. The implicit conversion of an `Array<T>` to an `UnsafeMutablePointer<T>` (e.g. `[CChar]` → `UnsafeMutablePointer<CChar>` in Swift == `char *` in C) does not allow you to *assign* an entirely new buffer to the array instance. You can write into the *contents* of the buffer by writing to pointer values, but you cannot allocate a new block of memory and reassign the contents of the array to that new block

Instead, you'll need to either:

1. Have `functionWithArray` return an entirely new array and length from C — you mention this isn't possible for `functionWithArray` specifically because of the other values it needs to return, but theoretically you can also create a C `struct` which wraps up all of the return values together and return one of those instead
2. Rewrite `functionWithArray` to receive an array and a length, and pre-reserve enough space in the array up-front to fill it appropriately:

   ```
   var letters: [CChar] = []
   letters.reserveCapacity(/* however much you need */)
   functionWithArray(&letters, letters.capacity)
   ```

   In `functionWithArray`, don't *reassign* letters, but instead fill it up to the `capacity` given to you with results. Of course, this will only work if you know in Swift ahead of time how much space `functionWithArray` will need, which you might not

   - Alternatively, you can also use [`Array.init(unsafeUninitializedCapacity:initializingWith:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/3200717-init) to combine these operations by having `Array` preallocate some space, and you can pass in the `inout UnsafeMutableBufferPointer<CChar>` to C where you *can*  allocate memory if you need to and assign to the buffer pointer, then write out to the `inout Int` how many array elements you allocated and initialized. This does also require a capacity, though, and is a more complicated solution

Of these two approaches, if `functionWithArray` really does need to dynamically reallocate memory and grow the buffer, then (1) is likely going to be easier.

Comment: Thank you so much! This was a very nice and clear explanation. Now I understand that the best way to accomplish my purpose is using a C struct. Thanks again!